# How to plot timeseries from particular starting date?

Tags: python, pandas

```
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries

ts = TimeSeries(key='YOUR_API_KEY', output_format='pandas')
data, meta_data = ts.get_daily('SPX')

data['4. close'].plot()
plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

[image: chart]

How to get new data timeseries starting from particular date? Or how to plot chart from particular starting datetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's `data`? I assume it's a `DataFrame`.

```
start_ts = pd.Timestamp("20180101")
data[data.index>=start_ts]["4. close"].plot()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked with little correction: data[data.index>='2018-01-01']["4. close"].plot()